# Access Renderer Scripts From Electron Main Menu

Tags: electron

I need to access renderer scripts from electron main menu via onclick. I've added the following to the electron main menu:

```
{
       label: 'Checking for Update',
       click: function () {
          require('./update')
       }
}

.........................

{
       label: `Preferences...`,
       click: function () { 
          require('./preferences')
       }
}
```

I'm trying to call `preferences.js` or `update.js` above. Both scripts working fine when calling directly from `index.html`, or from app window via onclick, but not from app menu. When clicked in main app menu its just erroring with

```
Uncaught Exception:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'app' of undefined
    at IncomingMessage.res.on (update.js:20:36)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at IncomingMessage.Readable.read (_stream_readable.js:381:10)
    at flow (_stream_readable.js:761:34)
    at resume_ (_stream_readable.js:743:3)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
```

update.js:20 looks like the following:

```
   const appname = electron.remote.app.getName()
```

There is no remote in the main menu process. Remote module belongs only to renderer so this seems to be reasonable error for me.

But I'm not quite sure how to easily fix this and make scripts work once called from app menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this could work:

```
const {app} = (process.type === 'renderer' ? require('electron').remote : require('electron'))
```

I think that should help to make your code main and renderer proof. Of course you have to change the rest of your code accordingly. `const appname = electron.remote.app.getName()` would just become `const appname = app.getName()`

Comment: Yeah, i implemented something similar. I will replace my checking logic by 'process.type'  per your suggestion since its much cleaner. Thanks! Marked as accepted.

Comment: `const {app, dialog} = require('electron').remote || require('electron')` would also work then.

Comment: short & sweet !

Answer (score 0):

I was able to workaround it as following:

```
const electron = require('electron')
const remote = electron.remote
```

---

```
if (remote) {    // remote will be 'undefined' when calling from the main process              
   const app = remote.app
   const dialog = remote.dialog 
   const window = remote.getCurrentWindow()
} else {
   const app = electron.app
   const dialog = electron.dialog 
   const window = electron.getCurrentWindow()
}
```